# Bot is not doing a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
    if (!message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}snipe`)) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_MESSAGES"])) return message.channel.send(`you cant snipe`);

        const msg = client.snipes.get(message.channel.id);
        if (!msg) return message.channel.send(`nothing to snipe :(`);

        const SnipeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(msg.author.tag, msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setDescription(msg.content)
            .setColor("RED").setImage(msg.image);

        message.channel.send(SnipeEmbed);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So first thing first you need to understand how if else works because u made a big mistake here

```
 - if (!message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}snipe`)) //If its not start with snipe. DO IT!
+ if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}snipe`))//if its starts with snipe DO IT!
```

So that wasn't let you to pass command second thing that will not work (thats my predictions) is:

```
- const msg = client.snipes.get(message.channel.id); //don't work
+ const smh = msg.client.snipes.get(message.channel.id);
```

I hope that helps you. Give feedback if it works :D